# How can I plot a legend in R without plotting symbols and still get it to align nicely?

Tags: r, plot, legend

Can I create a plot legend which doesn't have plotting symbols and that the text itself is fitted to the border box?

For example, in the following code there is a gap before the legend text that I want to get rid of:

```
plot(c(1,2,3),c(1,1,1))
abline(v=c(1.5,2,2.5),col=c("blue","red","green"))
legend("topright",legend=c("legend 1","legend 2","legend 3"),text.col=c("blue","red","green"))
```

Comment: you can play with `adj` parameter of `legend` function : try `adj=c(0.4,0.5)`

Comment: I find it sometimes nicer to have no border for the legend box at all; you could try `bty="n"`

Comment: Thanks @CathG. This helps bring the legend to a better position on the page but now the different lines of text are not left aligned (they seem to be centered but this is only obvious when the length of text differs (eg "legend 1", "leg 2", "3")).

Comment: Thanks @user1981275. This does make it nicer but I would also like to move the text further towards the middle of the plot.

Comment: @AnnaJackson, see my answer to have left-aligned text and closer border. I hope it does what you had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something you can try :

```
# draw your legend without the border and with the text left-aligned and save the components :
myleg<-legend("topright",legend=c("legend 1","legend 2","leg 3"),text.col=c("blue","red","green"),plot=T,bty="n")

# get the user coordinates to adjust the gap between the text and the border
coord<-par("usr")

# add a border, closer to the text (here, gap between border and beginning of text is a hundredth of the plot width) :
rect(myleg$text$x[1]-diff(coord[1:2])/100,myleg$rect$top-myleg$rect$h,myleg$rect$left+myleg$rect$w,myleg$rect$top)
```

[image]

***If you want to move the text further towards the middle of the plot, you can use `inset` parameter (eg: inset=0.05) :***

```
myleg<-legend("topright",legend=c("legend 1","legend 2","leg 3"),text.col=c("blue","red","green"),plot=T,inset=0.05,bty="n")
coord<-par("usr")
rect(myleg$text$x[1]-diff(coord[1:2])/100,myleg$rect$top-myleg$rect$h,myleg$rect$left+myleg$rect$w,myleg$rect$top)
```

[image]