# R - Boxplot with label in the left bottom corner

Tags: r, label, legend, boxplot

I want to put some labels into a boxplot, to show significance values. My favorite would be the position left bottom. I tried to do it with legend, but had the problem that I don't have any symbols to show and couldn't find anything to show the legend without symbols. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521394/how-can-i-plot-a-legend-in-r-without-plotting-symbols-and-still-get-it-to-align), but thought it's way too complicated. There should exist an easier solution.

If it's possible I would prefer to use the base R functionality and no plugin.

So [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtz4v.png) is how it looks like now and I want the labels (in rows) in the bottom left corner without the gap in the beginning.

Maybe the `legend` command isn't the command I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to write the text directly using the `text` function.
Since you do not provide your data, I will illustrate with some built-in data, but you will need to adjust the placement for your specific plot.

```
boxplot(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data=iris, ylim=c(1,5))
text(0.45,0.95, "1960-2002**\n2002-2012**\nt-test verb.", adj=c(0,0))
```

[image: Boxplot]

The `adj=c(0,0)` part is to left-justify the text.

If you want the box around the text, add:

```
rect(0,0,1.2,1.6)
```

You also can do this with legend and get rid of the gap by specifying the x,y coordinates of the legend. Once again,  you will need to adjust for your plot.

```
boxplot(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data=iris, ylim=c(1,5))
legend(0.23, 1.65, c("1960-2002**", "2002-2012**", "t-test verb."))
```

Comment: @d.b  That leaves the big gap that OP wanted to get rid of.

Comment: Yes,  could be done with `bottomleft` and `adj=c(0.25,0.25)`

Comment: ok, I have a problem to understand how it works with the coordinates (x,y), in this case 0.45 and 0.95. Why 0.95 for the y-axis, cause I think there is no scale, right? Or is this some kind of relative positioning?

Comment: There _is_ a scale on the y-axis.  On my plot, the y axis started just below 1,  On yours, it starts just below 20. You might want to start with y=20 and adjust so that it looks nice.

Comment: ups, sorry I mixed it up. I didn't mean the y-axis, I mean the x-axis..

Comment: Oh, The x-axis.  My boxplot had 3 boxes.  They are plotted at x = 1,2 and 3. In general, boxplot places n boxes at 1:n. One way that you can see that is to make a plot, then run `locator()` and click on the center lines of the boxes.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now as well as I got the example from the other question I posted in my first post (from User 'cath'). Her solution is actually quite nice, now that I understand it better, because I can automate it.